# Настройка интернет сервера

Tags: windows, ftp, teamviewer

В общем, попробую описать вопрос. Есть компьютер, на котором установлена обыкновенная ХР, с двумя сетевыми картами:

1. вход интернет провайдера,
2. выход на переключатель (раздача интернета), к которому включены остальные компьютеры.

На сервере установлен антивирус Essential Security и всё. Брандмауэр отключен. Если с этого сервера напрямую подключить к любому ftp адресу, то, как и должно быть, пускает. Если с любого другого компьютера зайти, то почему-то не пускает. Будто что-то блокирует. Но что? Если зайди через браузер на адрес: 192.168.0.1 (адрес сервера), то пишется что-то типа: работает на TeamViewer.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, или в курсе, подскажите, как открыть доступ на выход к FTP?

Comment: Речь об FTP сервере, который не на самом сервере?

Comment: Да, честно говоря, не очень понятное описание. Если ты имеешь ввиду интернет ftp, то, наверное, на сервере плохо настроил прокси.
Советую проверить, что настроен также ftp прокси, а не только http.

Comment: Да, интернет ФТП.

Сервер настраивал не я. Просто попросили разобраться в том, что понастраивал предыдущий администратор. В общем, хочу сказать, что в сервисах нашёл CCProxy, который просто не заметил. ) В настройках программы ФТП перебрассывается на 2121 порт. В браузере настроил прокси и для ФТП указал 2121 порт. И всё равно не работает интернет ftp.

Comment: Вероятно всё-таки настройка прокси. Для проверки можно попробовать указать в браузере на сервере работу через прокси и посмотреть - работает или нет. Скорее всего - нет. А вот с настройками CCProxy - тут я абсолютно не в курсе.

Answer (score 1):

Проброс портов нужен ..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключатся к ftp пассивно (как браузер) через total.
Вроде бы можно для этого использовать стандартный порт прокси.